# what should i use instead of Directory.SetCurrentDirecory?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce, multiplatform

i have a multi environment program that runs on windows ce machines, regular pc and windows mobile.
I am using a database and files.
because of the windows CE i need to use the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() func before the file use and then reset the current directory (using the Directory.SetCurrentDirectory() func) back to the old one because it changes once i do the I\O in order to continue using the DB.
because the windows mobile does not support this functions there is an exception thrown during runtime a "NotSupporetedException".
any functions that i could use instead of this that should fix my problem?
or any way i can check during runtime what environment the application is running on and not use this functions if the application runs on mobile?

please help,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your directory problem, but you can certainly check which platform you're on at runtime:

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.WinCE)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```